# 1mm² wire load capacity

Tags: wire

I have used a 1mm² wire to power my refrigerator and my ro water purifier? My electrician had set that up and he told me that he is using a 1.5mm² wire! so is 1mm² wire ok to power up my refrigerator and water purifier?  Any harm? please advice. Many thanks in advance

Comment: What do all the amounts of tables you can find on the interwebs say? And this is a comment because I cannot find my mindreading hat that would tell me how much amps your appliances draw...

Comment: My refrigerator say max 1.1A and idk about my water purifier! Is there not something like the max load the wire can handle before the insulation starts melting and burning?

Comment: Here's a chart: http://s.eeweb.com/members/cody_miller/answers/1319212670-cable-current-temp-chart.pdf  It tells you how hot a wire with a certain cross section will be when conducting a certain current. Unfortunately you don't specify how much current your devices will draw.

Comment: Why are you not using gauges and amperage for your comparison/assessment? For instance, I know offhand that 12 ga wire is suitable for 20 amp applications, 14ga for 15 amps, etc.

Comment: Thank you all! @ brown My compressor says 11 amps! So, I don't think it's cool for me to use a 1mm² wire! Isn't it? Should I go for a 1.5mm² wire or 2.5mm²?

Comment: I guess an even bigger question is, is this going to be a brand new circuit from your electrical panel, or are you splicing, joining to an existing circuit, etc?

Comment: @BrownRedHawk Now its a part of the house wiring running over 3-4 foot long! It is connected to a 2.5 mm² cable on one side and to a socket on the other side!

Comment: Then I would use at least 2.5mm wire, since going any thicker won't make a difference, compared to what would be thinner wiring throughout the house.

Comment: "Why are you not using gauges and amperage" -- Most likely eplanation would be that he lives in a place that doesn't work to american standards.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: Consult local electrical code, and/or utilize a licensed and experienced electrician.**

Typically there are code restrictions for what kind of supply wire should be present for different installations. This is usually a function of the Amperage of the system, not the device plugged in. For instance, a 20 amp service at 120 v in the US is typically required to be wired in 12 GA solid copper (or 3.31mm2).

Since this amperage is the primary concern, I would stick to anything larger than or equal to at least the equivalent of 14ga wire. However to minimize things like dimmer of other related circuits, I would stick to 12Ga wire where possible.

Wire size conversions - http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/awg-wire-gauge-d_731.html

Comment: I think you're slightly backwards.  The wire **is** sized to the load, and the breaker is sized to the wire.

Comment: @tester this is a good clarification. My explanation was more visual/functional than from the code's logic, but at the end of the day they should be matched.